# Is there a single word for "taking (or take) one for the team"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that sums up "taking one for the team"?

In this instance specifically doing work alone that would normally be done by a small group, so that others can rest.

- Loyalty
- Dedication
- Integrity
- Sacrifice

all seem to (me to) be sub-par.

Comment: I have heard the term. Just cannot remember what it is. It is driving me crazy.

Comment: @Jenna Glad to know I was not alone in my suffering...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few that would qualify: selflessness, self-denial, self-sacrifice, self-abnegation, etc. They all mean something like this [from NOAD]:

> **selflessness**
>   *adjective*
>   concerned more with the needs and wishes of others than with one's own; unselfish: *an act of selfless devotion*.

Comment: I feel that this does address my question as phrased.  If there are no answers that better fit the connotation I was thinking of, I'll accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. take one for the team
>      The act of someone willingly making a sacrifice for the benefit of others.
>
> Example: There wasn't enough room in the car, so Jerry decided to take one for the team and stayed behind while the rest of us went to the big concert.

**wingman, team player, sacrificial lamb, good sport, buddy**

> **self-abnegation** *n*
>
> the denial of one's own interests in favour of the interests of others
>   self-abnegating  adj
>
> **self-renunciation** *n*
>
> the renunciation of one's own rights, claims, interest, etc., esp in favour of those of others
>   self-renunciatory  adj

Comment: I haven't seen @Robusto 初夢 's self-abnegation my mistake. It will be good if you write these words in cursive or something so they would be more noticeable . Have a good one mate.

Answer (score 0):

- *[workhorse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/workhorse)*, "Anyone or thing that does a lot of work; who works consistently or regularly."
- *[spearhead](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spearhead)*, "One who leads or initiates an activity" [Also see *point* or *point-man*, *quarterback*, *matador*, etc.]
- *[martyr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyr)*, "somebody who suffers persecution and death for refusing to renounce... a belief or cause" ["The hero continues, despite knowing the risk, out of commitment to the cause" is listed as characteristic of martyrs]
- *[lead dog](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lead_dog)*,  "one of the dogs at the front of the team, who set the pace"
- *[mainspring](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mainspring)*, in sense "The most important reason for something", might refer to one who has been a main driver for a project
- *[yeoman](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yeoman)*, as in *yeoman effort*, refers to one who has "performed or rendered in a loyal, valiant, useful, or workmanlike manner, especially in situations that involve a great deal of effort or labor"

Of course none of the above precisely mean "doing work alone that would normally be done by a small group, so that others can rest", but some suggest hard, faithful, or important work being done, and calling a worker a *martyr* suggests sacrifice on his or her part.  *[Helot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helot)* may suggest working like a slave in spite of personal risk, but to some extent suggests a cog, lackey, flunkey, slave, dogsbody.

Comment: I really liked yeoman, but self-abnegation also came close and it was first.